# Jsoup разбор таблицы

Tags: java

Есть таблица со строкой

```
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">001686</td>
<td>Сергей Ультрапак</td>
<td><p align="right">600,00</p></td>     
</tr>
```

как с помощью jsoup найти строку по значение первого столбца (001686) и достать в этой строке значение третьего столбца (600,00).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если только jsoup, то как-то так. Нужно создать список всех нужных рядков соответствующим селектором и проверять значение каждого столбца.

```
 Elements elements = doc.select("селектор на tr таблицы");
     for (Element e : elements) {
         Elements tds = e.select("td");

         if(tds.get(0).text().equals("001686")){
             System.out.println(tds.get(2).text());
         }
 }
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ решение работает. Если есть лучше вариант, то просьба в студию.